# show just own posts of custom-post-type to wordpress user

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I have a custom post type called "task". Actually every wordpress backend user sees every "task" which has been published by every user. 
I have two user roles "admin" & "shop_manager". What i need is that the admin sees every task and the shop_manager sees just the task published by himself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
if ( is_admin() && !current_user_can('manage_options') ):

global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
$author_query = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'author' => $current_user->ID
);

$author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);

while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    

<?php           
endwhile;

else :

echo "not logged in";

endif;
```

Comment: Yea i tried this. But this shows own posts from all post types. I just need a solution for the post type "task".

Comment: I've change the code a bit, try this.

Comment: What about using the `post_type` parameter or if you go with `pre_get_posts` approach the `is_singular()` conditional can be used.